# PIVOT on multiple columns SQL server (Aspen Relay Database)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, cross-apply

I'm using a vendor supplied Relay Database (Aspen), which is running on MS SQL server). I'm attempting to write a pivot query that needs to pivot on 2 columns.

I created a temp table since the data is across multiple tables.

```
WITH TEMP_TABLE AS (
  SELECT 
    R.LOCATIONID LLOCATIONID, R.ID RID, s.groupname SGROUPNAME,t.settingname TSETTINGNAME, s.setting SSETTING
from tsetting1 s
inner join tsettype1 t on t.relaytype=s.relaytype and t.groupname = s.groupname and t.rownumber = s.rownumber
INNER JOIN TREQUEST Q ON S.REQUESTID = Q.ID
INNER JOIN TRELAY R ON R.ID = Q.RELAYID
INNER JOIN TLOCATION L ON L.ID = R.LOCATIONID
where s.requestid=29117
)
select  * from TEMP_TABLE
```

That select all from Temp returns 38 rows of data, a subset is shown here:

```
RID -----SGROUPNAME------TSETTINGNAME-------SSETTING
31297    LOAD1            ENABLE             TRUE
31297    LOAD1            ANGLE              60
31297    LOAD2            CALCULATED_LOAD    12269
ETC....
```

I added this pivot, which gets me close:

```
PIVOT (MAX(SSETTING) FOR TSETTINGNAME IN (ENABLE, REACH, ANGLE, CALCULATED_LOADABILITY, ZLE, CTR, PTR, KVNOM, PICKUP, PERCENTAGE)) P
```

Returned result from Pivot:

```
RID-----SGROUPNAME-----ENABLE----REACH----ANGLE----CALCULATED_LOADABILITY
31297   LOAD1          TRUE      15       60       9444
31297   LOAD2          TRUE      10       30       12269
31297   LOAD3          TRUE      20       60       14167
ETC...
```

I would like to have the data as 1 record for RID 31297, where LOAD1-ENABLE, LOAD2-ENABLE, LOAD3-ENABLE, LOAD1-REACH, ETC. are all headers.

I've tried multiple pivots and cross apply, but I can't seem to get the data to display correctly.

Let me know if anything is unclear or if you need more information. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Joe C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier with a bunch of case statements and a group by RID. By the way this is the "original" method of pivoting before PIVOT was implemented.

```
select RID
   , Load1_Enable = MAX(case when SGROUPNAME = 'Load1' then enable else null end)
   , Load2_Enable = MAX(case when SGROUPNAME = 'Load2' then enable else null end)
from [YourTable]
group by RID
```

I would go all the way to the first cte though:

```
WITH TEMP_TABLE AS (
  SELECT 
    R.LOCATIONID LLOCATIONID, R.ID RID, s.groupname SGROUPNAME,t.settingname TSETTINGNAME, s.setting SSETTING
from tsetting1 s
inner join tsettype1 t on t.relaytype=s.relaytype and t.groupname = s.groupname and t.rownumber = s.rownumber
INNER JOIN TREQUEST Q ON S.REQUESTID = Q.ID
INNER JOIN TRELAY R ON R.ID = Q.RELAYID
INNER JOIN TLOCATION L ON L.ID = R.LOCATIONID
where s.requestid=29117
)
select RID
    ,Load1_Enable = MAX(case when SGROUPNAME = 'Load1' and TSETTINGNAME = 'Enable' then SSETTING else null end)
from TEMP_TABLE
group by RID
```

Note MAX is only there for an aggregate -- you should be aggregating only one record.

Comment: Thank you. It's a pretty long list of case statements, but it works exactly as I wanted. I appreciate the help. Got to use the right tool for the right job